# ui-grid height is overriding my css

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am trying to get the ui-grid to fill my container using flexbox.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: flex;">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" style="flex-grow: 1"></div>
</div>
```

I have also tried using absolute positioning with top,left, right, bottom = 0 with the same incorrect results.

The grid appears to be setting the height internally instead of listening to the html/css.

I have tried overriding the ui-grid css with

```
.ui-grid {
  height: 100% !important;
}
.ui-grid-viewport {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

which only partially works.  When the grid doesn't have rows, the horizontal scroll bar is right below the header.   I want the grid and scroll bars to fill the container so the scrollbars are on the left and bottom.

I do not want to use the ui-grid-auto-resize module as it is performance problem.

Is there a solution to get ui-grid to use the css specified?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to be more specific on the css

Here is a post https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3150

That address direct changes on the ui-grid css:

For Example:

```
.ui-grid-menu .ui-grid-menu-inner {
box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 12px 12px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.ui-grid-menu .ui-grid-menu-inner ul li:hover {
/* remove box shadow */
background: #ddd;
}
```

That's the most specific you can get,

Hope it helps.